# How to check if an element in a sub array is present in other sub arrays of an array and sorting via the value of the 1st index

Tags: javascript

The sample array below is obtained from a csv file, then converted to an array with sub arrays. Every array is basically one row in the csv file.

First index to the last index is categorised as follows: orderid, shopid, userid, date and time.

My goal here is to sort is via orderid, so that the user id's match. Now I would like to check if the shopid element in one sub array is present in other sub arrays.

Example of what I mean would be using CTRL + F on a list for example, and entering the item you are looking for. It grabs the element value, and uses it to search through all of the sub arrays in the same index.

Another if statement would come into play here if that first condition is met, if the concentrate rate of the shop is `>= 3` *WITHIN ONE HOUR OF FIRST TRANSACTION OF THE SHOP* then it would be considered as orderbrushing. If it is considered as order brushing, one of things would happen, one being if there is only one consistent userid buying, then we compile the data by shopid and userid in an array, separated by a comma.

The other thing that would happen if there are multiple user ids purchasing from the shop, then we would compile the shopid as usual but for the userids, we would have to join them together, for example:

```
userid1&userid306
```

in the same string. The results should have an array with sub arrays that contain 2 indexes, `shopid` and `userids`.

Example of the expected output:

```
sample array:
 [[ '31075200506751', '6042309', '97707522', '12/27/2019 0:00' ],
  [ '31075200506752', '104804492', '97707522', '12/27/2019 0:00' ],
  [ '31075200506753', '8715449', '97707522', '12/27/2019 0:00' ],
  [ '31075201870570', '190969466', '170182475', '12/27/2019 0:00' ],
  [ '31075205798263', '65551316', '12532131', '12/27/2019 0:00' ],
  [ '31075205798264', '2859407', '12532131', '12/27/2019 0:00' ],
  [ '31075205798265', '94479614', '12532131', '12/27/2019 0:00' ],
  [ '31075207143536', '26218382', '128755891', '12/27/2019 0:00' ],
  [ '31075207143537', '127236302', '128755891', '12/27/2019 0:00' ],
  [ '31075207143538', '54615708', '128755891', '12/27/2019 0:00' ],
  [ '31075207143539', '137739819', '128755891', '12/27/2019 0:00' ],
  [ '31075207143540', '18784836', '128755891', '12/27/2019 0:00' ],
  [ '31075208826809', '147941492', '195903090', '12/27/2019 0:00' ],
  [ '31075210701814', '31733346', '91112850', '12/27/2019 0:00' ],
  [ '31075210701815', '57934775', '91112850', '12/27/2019 0:00' ],
  [ '31075211185815', '9374147', '214198595', '12/27/2019 0:00' ],
  [ '31075212032449', '147941492', '210365192', '12/27/2019 0:00' ]]
```

Expected Output:

```
[14791492, 210365192]
```

Comment: Can you add some more info about your client/server side technologies?

Comment: What do you mean? @AjayKumar